# Mapping a class that contains references to another class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have something like this:

```
class A ():
   [...]

class B ():
   def __init__(self):
   self.fubar = A()
```

And I would like to store B into a database via [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/). I think that I need to define both `A` and `B` as two different tables -- mapping all the other properties of `A` and `B` appropriately.  Then, I need to map `A` to `B` as a property but I am not sure how to do that.

Is my thinking good or did I miss something?  Any idea what functions call I am missing -- or what page of the documentation covers it?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understood what you are asking. My immediate answer would be: "Wouldn't pickling an object and storing it in a text field suffice?"

Comment: @mac: Sadly not, although +1 for effort.  I need to be able to edit the properties of A via the database -- or rather an external piece of code needs to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indeed define two database entities, `A` and `B`, and a 1:1 or 1:n relationship between those two:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'b'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.id'))

    foobar = relationship('A')

    def __init__(self):
        self.foobar = A()
```

For a real-world example, read [the ORM tutorial](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-relationship), where your class `A` is named `User` and `B` `Address`.